# What to do if ex changes child school without my consent? (UK)

Tags: united-kingdom, children, school, parental-rights

If one parent changes their child's school without the others consent (both have Parental Responsibility), what can the other parent do to cancel that?

The current school's new vacancy might be filled very quick, teh child might not be able to get back to it if a court order takes only a few weeks. Is there such a thing as emergency court order for this? (if so, how long does it take?)

Answer (score 2):

In Australia you can seek an injunction in a court of competent jurisdiction; for a family law matter this is the Family Court. You will usually have a hearing and a ruling within 24 to 48 hours. Given that you don’t know this, it’s probably something you will need a lawyer for.

Comment: It would probably also be a good idea to contact the school to inform them that you expect your daughter to be returning to them (assuming a ruling in your favor), so that they know not to fill her spot too quickly.